# Solr OutOfMemory

Tags: java, solr, out-of-memory, jetty-8

I have Solr 4.2.1 running on Jetty 8.1.8 under Windows Server 2008 with x64 Java (JRE 7) and 2GB heap size. Solr index contains about 300-400k documents. About 3-5k new docs are added per day (mostly small, not more than 1-2kb). After about 1-2 days of work random `OutOfMemoryError` begin to appear on search requests, with almost same stack trace (until `CompressingStoredFieldsReader.readField`it is same as all).

I'm new to Solr and have no idea what could cause an error in that case.
Sample stack trace:

```
at java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.<init>(<unknown string>)
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(<unknown string>)
   Local Variable: char[]#6587
at java.lang.StringCoding.safeTrim(<unknown string>)
at java.lang.StringCoding.decode(<unknown string>)
at java.lang.String.<init>(<unknown string>)
at java.lang.String.<init>(<unknown string>)
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.compressing.CompressingStoredFieldsReader.readField(CompressingStoredFieldsReader.java:154)
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.compressing.CompressingStoredFieldsReader.visitDocument(CompressingStoredFieldsReader.java:272)
   Local Variable: org.apache.lucene.store.ByteArrayDataInput#1
   Local Variable: org.apache.lucene.codecs.compressing.CompressingStoredFieldsReader#97
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.document(SegmentReader.java:139)
at org.apache.lucene.index.BaseCompositeReader.document(BaseCompositeReader.java:116)
at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.doc(SolrIndexSearcher.java:643)
   Local Variable: org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher$SetNonLazyFieldSelector#1
at org.apache.solr.highlight.DefaultSolrHighlighter.doHighlighting(DefaultSolrHighlighter.java:384)
   Local Variable: java.util.HashSet#505
   Local Variable: java.lang.String[]#22
   Local Variable: org.apache.solr.common.util.SimpleOrderedMap#13
   Local Variable: org.apache.solr.search.DocSlice#15
   Local Variable: org.apache.solr.search.DocSlice$1#1
   Local Variable: org.apache.solr.highlight.DefaultSolrHighlighter#3
   Local Variable: org.apache.lucene.search.vectorhighlight.FieldQuery#1
   Local Variable: org.apache.lucene.search.vectorhighlight.FastVectorHighlighter#1
   Local Variable: org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher#1
   Local Variable: org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema#2
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.HighlightComponent.process(HighlightComponent.java:139)
   Local Variable: java.lang.String[]#21
   Local Variable: org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery#54
   Local Variable: org.apache.solr.handler.component.HighlightComponent#2
   Local Variable: org.apache.solr.common.params.DefaultSolrParams#1
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:208)
   Local Variable: org.apache.solr.handler.component.ResponseBuilder#1
   Local Variable: java.util.ArrayList$Itr#1
at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
   Local Variable: org.apache.solr.util.stats.TimerContext#1
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1817)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:639)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:345)
   Local Variable: org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer#1
   Local Variable: org.apache.solr.servlet.cache.Method#1
   Local Variable: org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrRequestParsers#1
   Local Variable: org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler#2
   Local Variable: org.apache.solr.response.SolrQueryResponse#1
   Local Variable: org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig#2
   Local Variable: java.lang.String#2256
   Local Variable: java.lang.String#2255
   Local Variable: org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrRequestParsers$1#1
   Local Variable: org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore#2
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:141)
   Local Variable: org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain#1
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1307)
   Local Variable: org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter#1
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:453)
   Local Variable: org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain#2
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:560)
   Local Variable: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Authentication$1#1
   Local Variable: org.eclipse.jetty.security.RoleInfo#1
   Local Variable: org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler#1
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1072)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:382)
   Local Variable: org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler#1
   Local Variable: org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder#1
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
   Local Variable: org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler#1
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1006)
   Local Variable: javax.servlet.DispatcherType#1
   Local Variable: org.eclipse.jetty.start.Classpath$Loader#1
   Local Variable: java.lang.String#2253
   Local Variable: java.lang.String#7243
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
   Local Variable: org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext#1
   Local Variable: org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection#1
   Local Variable: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler[]#2
   Local Variable: org.eclipse.jetty.http.PathMap#1
   Local Variable: org.eclipse.jetty.http.PathMap$Entry#1
   Local Variable: org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncContinuation#2
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
   Local Variable: org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection#1
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:365)
   Local Variable: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response#2
   Local Variable: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request#2
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:485)
   Local Variable: java.lang.String#2252
   Local Variable: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#1
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:926)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:988)
   Local Variable: org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler#2
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:635)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
   Local Variable: org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser#2
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
   Local Variable: org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection#2
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
   Local Variable: org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint#2
at java.lang.Thread.run(<unknown string>)
```

Comment: You add the JVM arg `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` and analyse the dump with a profiler.

Comment: @samlewis I did it. Stack trace is from that dumps. However I didn't find anything in that dumps that can help me. :(

Comment: Can you paste some sample queries which are giving OOM errors? Most of OOM errors are caused by unoptimized queries? Also what is your index size?

Comment: @Saumitra It's about 6gb, 300-400k documents. My sample solr query: `{!boost b=sum(sub(1,norm(text)),recip(ms(NOW,dateCreated),3.16e-11,1,1))}(companyID:2)AND(isPublic:true OR (isPublic:false AND groupID:(242 260 395 190 176 72 67 12))) AND ((title:(test*^12)) OR (title_ft:(test^6) OR text:(test^3)))`

Comment: I guess that might be because of highlighter have to reanalyze documents. I added termVectors, termPositions and termOffsets to `text` field (it's biggest one by content). Will check if it helped out in a two weeks, after deploy.